# List all tables in database

Tags: r, sqlite, dplyr

I have a local database and I am using `dplyr` to connect to it:

```
test_db <- src_sqlite("~/db/test_db.sqlite3")
```

I want to list all the tables in `test_db`.

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`?src_tbls`

in your case:

`src_tbls(test_db)`